# Domain relational calculus to relational algebra

Tags: databases, relational-algebra

I have an expression in DRC $\{\langle a,b,c \rangle \mid \langle a,b \rangle \in r \land \langle a,b \rangle \in s\}$, where $r = (A,B)$ and $s = (A,C)$. I want to convert it onto relational algebra and got this: 
$π_{A,B,C}(σ_{r.A = s.A \land r.B = s.C}(rxs))$ and I am not sure if it is correct...

Can someone explain if it is correct? Why it is correct or why it is not?

Comment: We don't usually check answers to exercises, unless you have a specific doubt (beyond not being sure whether the solution is correct).

Comment: Your DRC formula looks wrong to me. Shouldn't the r.h. side of the conjunction be `<a, c> ∈ s`? Your RA is almost certainly wrong. Read about Natural Join https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Natural_join_.28.E2.8B.88.29